# Suggesting for additional interesting tabs

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

Among the new tabs, there are ways of selecting "unanswered" and "need answers" for all the categories besides interesting. This seems like a nice feature to have if I am browsing for questions to answer since I will most likely know answers to the ones I consider interesting.